# What's the long ID in the path of iOS apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

On my jailbroken iOS device I can see that all App Store apps are located in individual directories in `/private/var/mobile/Applications/` named with a long identifier (eg `2075E7C0-D2EF-5A4F-B356-3EECDC9F7B38`). Does this serve a purpose, other than preventing conflicts between apps with the same names? Why don't Cydia apps stored in `/private/var/stash/Applications/` have such an ID in their paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifier is generated randomly on install and it is one of the sandbox requirements.